# How to insert src into String of iFrame?

Tags: html, iframe

I want to insert my String as src into this String;

```
    String my_scr="http://blabla..." is a variable will be  changed fromtime to time
```

how to put **my_scr** into  the String below ?  means it should replace http://youtube...

```
 String frameVideo = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"https://www.youtube.com/embed/47yJ2XCRLZs\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
```

if I put it like below, it does not work :

```
String frameVideo = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\my_scr frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to break out of your quotes as `my_src` is a variable:

```
frameVideo = "<html><body>Video From YouTube<br><iframe width=\"420\" height=\"315\" src=\"" + my_scr + "\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>"
```